# Android lollipop java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm currently working on a Android application that connects to a device via Bluetooth using Eclipse (Java). Currently I have it working on Android 4.4 (Kit-Kat) and below, but after the new update which is Android 5 (Lollipop). Security exception occurs.

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="false" />
```

Code:

```
mBleScanner.startScan(filters, scanSettings, mLeScanCallback);

private ScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new ScanCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result)
    {
        BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
        if(device.getName() != null)
        {
            if(device.getName().toUpperCase().contains("MyDevice"))
            {

                mBleScanner.stopScan(mLeScanCallback);

                if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED)
                {
                    Connect(device.getAddress().toString()); 
                }
                else
                {
                    // pair device
                    device.setPairingConfirmation(true);
                    device.createBond();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
...
..
.
private void BondDevice(BluetoothGattCharacteristic bgc, boolean pnEnable)
{
    boolean bool = gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(bgc, true); // this line throw security exception
    BluetoothGattDescriptor bgd=bgc.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(BLE_DESCRIPTOR_NOTIFY));

    byte[] arrayOfByte = pnEnable ? BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE:
                      BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE;
    gattDescriptor.setValue(arrayOfByte);
    mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(bgd);
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
04-27 12:36:24.559: W/BluetoothGatt(17764): Unhandled exception in callback
04-27 12:36:24.559: W/BluetoothGatt(17764): java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED permission: Neither user 10215 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED.
04-27 12:36:24.559: W/BluetoothGatt(17764):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
04-27 12:36:24.559: W/BluetoothGatt(17764):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
04-27 12:36:24.559: W/BluetoothGatt(17764):     at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.registerForNotification(IBluetoothGatt.java:1163)
04-27 12:36:24.559: W/BluetoothGatt(17764):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGatt.java:1239)
04-27 12:36:24.559: W/BluetoothGatt(17764):     at com.vibease.ap3.service.ServiceBLE.BondDevice(ServiceBLE.java:568)
04-27 12:36:24.559: W/BluetoothGatt(17764):     at com.vibease.ap3.service.ServiceBLE.CheckDevice(ServiceBLE.java:518)
04-27 12:36:24.559: W/BluetoothGatt(17764):     at com.vibease.ap3.service.ServiceBLE.access$7(ServiceBLE.java:493)
04-27 12:36:24.559: W/BluetoothGatt(17764):     at com.vibease.ap3.service.ServiceBLE$2.onServicesDiscovered(ServiceBLE.java:373)
04-27 12:36:24.559: W/BluetoothGatt(17764):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onSearchComplete(BluetoothGatt.java:309)
04-27 12:36:24.559: W/BluetoothGatt(17764):     at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:217)
04-27 12:36:24.559: W/BluetoothGatt(17764):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

Comment: try <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" />

Comment: The problem still exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Google change some security on the Bluetooth chip. My Bluetooth chip contain some part in the address that was block by this security. That's why I encountered my problem. Since I used a different chip. Everything works fine now.

P/s: forgot to answer this long time ago

Answer (score 1):

> 04-27 12:36:24.559: W/BluetoothGatt(17764): java.lang.SecurityException: Need `BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED` permission: Neither user 10215 nor current process has `android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED`.

Just add the permission it's asking for:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
```

Comment: That results in an error:
**PackageManager: Not granting permission android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED to package com.myapp.me (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x3848be46)**

Answer (score -1):

```
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

What is your target SDK version? Does your app support lollipop?

Comment: Yes it support lolipop, <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />

Comment: The problem still exist